# Excel VBA equivalent to Word VBA System

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a Word VBA function that I'm trying to build in Excel VBA (the reason behind this choice comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993589/how-to-access-a-word-public-variable-in-excel-vba?noredirect=1#comment57722516_34993589)) and I'm stuck at the following problem:

The Word VBA function uses `System.PrivateProfileString` extensively, which throws the `Compile Error: invalid qualifier` error when applied to Excel VBA. What's the equivalent statement in Excel? Alternatively, how do I work my way around this?

Example of use:

```
strHomeSharePath = System.PrivateProfileString("", "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment", "HOMESHARE")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read the registry in Excel you can do it this way.

```
Sub test()
Dim strPath As String
    strPath = RegKeyRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment\HOMESHARE")
End Sub

Function RegKeyRead(i_RegKey As String) As String
Dim myWS As Object

  On Error Resume Next
  'access Windows scripting
  Set myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  'read key from registry
  RegKeyRead = myWS.RegRead(i_RegKey)
End Function
```

Comment: Hell yeah! This is nice. Quick question: this function sends me to a `.ini` file, which has a header such as `[Header Text]` and several entries/keys below, such as "Company=company name". Trying to access the entries returns the error "Invalid root in registry key". Any idea how I can specifically return the value of a key?

Comment: @Holene Can you Post some Code? Because i don't understand your Question.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I did some more searching, and what I'm basically asking is if there is an easy way to read `.ini` files in Excel VBA?

Comment: @Holene [VBA Read Text File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185865/vba-read-all-text-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (as per your other question) your Excel code has a reference to a word Object, let's say "objWord", it should be...

```
strHomeSharePath = objWord.System.PrivateProfileString("", "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment", "HOMESHARE")
```

IMO the word "System" is a bit misleading, suggesting that it isn't to do with Word. But it's a class in the Word library.